# How to invoke root privileges from my custom app?

Tags: sudo, root, gui, application

In a GUI-environment, I want to be able to ask the user for the root/sudo password and then execute an app that requires root privileges from within my app.

As an example, say I want to run an editor to edit `/etc/fstab`, I need to start the editor via `exec()` or something with root privileges... how do I do this?

**Note:** gksu, gksudo is not an option - may not be available/installed

Comment: You will probably have to use gksu/kdesu anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:**

To run the "df -h" command as root:

```
su -c "df -h"
```

This will prompt the user for root password.

**Method 2:**

Alternatively, in /etc/sudoers find this line:

root    ALL=(ALL) ALL

and duplicate it for your user johnsmith that you want to give admin privileges:

johnsmith    ALL=(ALL) ALL

This way, johnsmith will be able to run any command requiring root rights, by first typing "sudo" in front of the command:

```
sudo df -h
```

**Method 3:**

You can use ssh to execute a command on the same machine:

```
ssh root@localhost "def -h"
```

will execute the same command in your server. If you don't want to be prompted for password, follow this tutorial for passwordless ssh:

http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

**Method 4:**

Use gksudo (graphical sudo):

```
gksudo "gnome-open %u"
```

Or, on KDE `kdesu`:

```
kdesu <command>
```

Comment: Method 1 won't work, he said it's a gui app.

Comment: These are all command-line techniques. I need to do it programmatically in a GUI setup.

Comment: GUI apps can execute shell commands. I added Method 4, which could be the GUI solution you are looking for.

Comment: Often, `ssh` is configured to not allow `root` access. And `sudo` is frequently shipped with the creation of a group. It is enough to add a user to the group to gain the privilege to use sudo, without tampering with `sudoers`.

Comment: These seem to be the options I have to work with, unless I track through the spaghetti-monster source-code of gksu/gksudo/kdesu to see how they do it.

Comment: I think that using gksude/kdesu "as is" is the best option because they are the standard prompts for their respective environments, so they are what the user is already expecting.